# redirect links using htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

How do I redirect a link to a particular link using .htaccess

```
http://www.example.com/one http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/
http://www.example.com/two http://differentdomain.co.uk/b/
http://www.example.com/three http://differentdomain.co.uk/c/
http://www.example.com/four http://differentdomain.co.uk/d/
```

i have tried Redirect 301 & RewriteRule but its not working at all, im using an apache server

This is what i have on my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options +Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/one http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

both these codes dont work for me

```
Redirect 301 /one/ http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/
RewriteRule ^/one http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/ [R=301,L]
```

by the way the domain I'm working on is empty only the .htaccess & cgi-bin folder is present

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^/?one/?$ http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/ [R=301,L]` as your first rule in root .htaccess

Comment: hi, what is the purpose of $ sign and ^ sign, sorry very new here

Comment: There are regex anchors. `^` is for start and `$` is for matching end position.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try your code

Comment: Hi, i've tried your code and it gives me a 404, it only changed the domain like http://www.domain.com/one it redirected to http://differentdomain.co.uk/one/ instead of http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/

Comment: Remove `Redirect 301 /one/ http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/` if you still have it and clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think (not sure) `Redirect` directive doesn't work because you don't have `/one` path in your root.

try this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^one http://differentdomain.co.uk/a/ [R=301,L]
```